# TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object to Array

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, red5, coercion

i have a Problem with the understanding of Sending Objects,Variable or else from my Red5 Java Server Application to a AS3 Script.

The Problem im Facing is that i wrote down the following code in Java:

```
        ((IServiceCapableConnection) conn).invoke("say", params);
```

It invokes a Method in my ActionScript that calls "say" with his Parameters called "params".
So far so good.

My ActionScript looks like:

```
        public function say(user:Array):void{
            var usr:Array = user  as UserVO;
            list.appendText(usr[0] + "\n");
        }
```

So it gets the Array but i cant use it its tells me that cause the following Error:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@123b4a7f1 to Array.

So can someone tell me how to "Convert" this Part right? i saw some Articles about serializing but didnt get the Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserVO` isn't compatible with `Array`:

```
 var usr:Array = user  as UserVO;
```

You may try this:

```
 var usr:UserVO = user[0] as UserVO;// or similar in a for loop
```

It would be good if you verify following:

**Java**:

```
package abc;
public class UserVO implements Serializable { .. }
```

**AS**:

```
[Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="abc.UserVO")]
    public class UserVO 
    { .. }
```

Comment: Ty, hatsh for your Comment but i still get this Exception 

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@10957eac1 to Array.

May i should do the converting in a for loop for every Value?

Comment: On which line you get this error? can you also post what is `params` which you are passing in `Java` invocation..

Comment: ah sry forgot to post it...

Object[] params = new Object[] {user};

User is a Value Object that holds all my user attributes. Its build like: 

public class UserVO {
 private int id;
 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
}

Comment: edited my comment, Java `UserVO` should `implement Serializable`

Comment: Thank you very much but im now getting the following Exception:
  TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  I will search for this one now but u helped me a lot.

Comment: I tried the Script what were posted from harsh and im still getting this exception:  
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference  
As i debuged the Application i saw that the Object usr still void and dont get any Content.  
the Exception were caused from the following source:  
var usr:UserVO = user[0] as UserVO;   
What im making not right ? Anyone have clues?  
I'm thankfull for every Post